# Can I delete the relative adverb "where" anytime?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Can I say, "You can stand in the house Romeo and Juliet fell in love." 
In this case, relative adverb 'where' was deleted. But I think there should be "in" at the end of the sentence. Am I right? Can anyone answer about this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to insert either *in* or *where*. The reason is that you generally cannot delete *where* but in certain cases you can delete *that/which*. Consider the following two sentences:

> This is the house which/that Romeo and Juliet fell in love in.
>
> This is the house where Romeo and Juliet fell in love.

You cannot delete *where* from the second sentence, but you can delete *which/that* from the first.

Comment: S D Gundam gives a more detailed answer at [wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=282370). '.. . HOWEVER, sometimes you CAN omit relative adverbs if the relative clause occurs at the end of the sentence and the meaning of the sentence will still be readily understood. Examples:

"The office is the place where you spend most of your life."
(Original clause: You spend most of your life there.)
"The office is the place you spend most of your life." '

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Armen, that seem to be very much a feature of the word "place". "Place" seems to have some weird properties. For example, when constructions take "place" as a goal, it seems to obviate the need for a preposition quite often. *Let's go some place.* etc

Comment: @Araucaria And more so in the US. With my examples, I'd claim that "The office is the place where you spend most of your life" is more idiomatic. We'd have to use your 'Let's go some place' though, or rephrase to say 'Let's go somewhere'.